# Port forwarding between NIC cards

Tags: windows-7, port, forwarding

I have a network in the 192.168.10.xxx range. On one of the computers on the network there are two NICs. One NIC is in the 192.168.10.xxx subnet, connected to the main network. The other NIC is in the 10.10.0.xxx subnet. The 10.10.0.xxx NIC connects to a remote security camera. I would like to be able to see the security camera from a browser on a different computer in the 192.168.10.xxx subnet.
Is it possible to forward a port in Windows 7 to allow me to do this? Please be specific

Answer (score 0):

So you have a computer with two NICs.  One faces the 192.168.10.0/24 network, and I assume it already has an IP like 192.168.10.1 or similar.

All you should need to do is assign the NIC connected to the camera's network 10.10.0.0/24 an IP in that range, such as 10.10.0.253 or something else that is not used.  From this machine with two NIC cards, you should be able to reach anything on either subnet without the use of anything else.

All local NICs automatically give you a route into the networks they connect to, by virtue of being directly connected.  If you are directly connected to two networks, you can reach either one without needing anything else.

Ok, I more fully read your question and you want to reach the camera through another computer.  On Windows, the easiest way to do this will be to run a program that listens on the 192.168.10.0/24 NIC and forwards incoming traffic on a specific port to the camera's IP.

[Look here](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm) for Simple TCP Proxy or Simple UDP Proxy.  These are command line utilities but they should work.

Comment: One important thing, This kind of setup with two NIC's is called "MultiHomed". Windows does not support more than one Gateway in a multihome setup if the two networks are not connected.